# How to call a function in another Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-function

I need to write a script that creates and calls a function named `fnItemTotal` that calculates the total amount of an item in the `OrderItems` table (discount price multiplied by quantity).

To do that, this function should accept one parameter for the item ID, it should use the DiscountPrice function that I created earlier and it should return the value of the total for that item.

---

This is my Function I created and it gets created. But when i try to call it it gives an error.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnItemTotal 
        (@ItemID INT )
    RETURNS MONEY
BEGIN
RETURN 
    (
        SELECT 
            ItemId,
            (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnDiscountPrice(ItemID) WHERE ItemID=@ItemID)*Quantity)--The fnDiscountPrice is the Other function i created.
        FROM 
            OrderItems
        WHERE 
            ItemID=@ItemID
    );
END 
GO
```

---

This is what I'm using to call it:

```
Select ItemID,dbo.fnItemTotal(ItemID) AS 'Total Price'
from OrderItems 
ORDER BY ItemID;
```

---

This is the ERROR it gives me when I call it:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.fnDiscountPrice'.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you created the `fnDiscountPrice` function in the `dbo` schema? Are you absolutely sure the function exists within the database you are running the function from?

Comment: Yea i still had the script up from where i created it.@TT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnItemTotal 
    (@ItemID INT )
RETURNS MONEY
BEGIN
DECLARE @X as MONEY 

        SELECT @X = dbo.fnDiscountPrice(ItemID) *  OrderItems.Quantity 
        FROM 
            OrderItems
        WHERE 
            OrderItems.ItemID=@ItemID

            RETURN @X

END
```

Comment: This didn't work eithe it says that the item id is ambiguous @H.Fadlallah

Comment: the main problem was that the function return money by syntax and in real it return a table

Comment: This Worked Thank You Very Much @H.Fadlallah